# How to use useImperative Handle react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new in react and i'm still learn react hook, i have done knowing
the purpose of useImperativeHandle. But i have an problem with the syntax below is the code example:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import {forwardRef,useRef,useImperativeHandle} from 'react'

const ChildComponent = forwardRef(
  function reference(props,ref){
    const refs = useRef(null);
    useImperativeHandle(ref,() => {
      return {
        sayHi: () => {
          console.log("hello world");
        }
      }
    });

    return(
      <div ref={refs}>{refs.current}</div>
    );
  }
);

function ParentComponent(){
  const refs = useRef("HELLO World");
  function sayHello(){
    refs.current.sayHi();
  }
  sayHello();
  return(
    <ChildComponent ref={refs}/>
  );
}
const div_root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
div_root.render(<ParentComponent/>);
```

from about code i got an error where sayHi is not a function, which part in my code that have a wrong syntax

Comment: `ref` (imperative or otherwise) will not be available during component mounting. Move any code that uses refs in an effect instead

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you are trying to access the DOM element before it has been mounted, that is, it has entered the componentDidMount state. That's why you can't use it that way. You need to call the function, for example, in useEffect with an empty dependency array, or upon some action with the element, for example on click.